# UiTabViewControllers+UINavigationControllers+UIViewControllers Orientation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, orientation

I have a UITabViewController application with 4 tabs and each tab with a UINavigationController, each with a UItableView. When a row is clicked it navigates to another view.
I would like to support Landscape Orientation only for a certain UIViewController and not in any other view.
When I set "return YES" on each UINavigationcontrollers (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method the app orients in all the views even in the uitableview.
How do I get this right? I am very confused

Comment: Are you defining the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method in the navigation controller or the table view controller?

Comment: I am defining the shouldAutorotateInterfaceOrientation method in the navigation controllers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the views as per your requirement then you have to make different view for each tab also in Interface builder you have to create landscape view wherever you required. When you add that landscape view, which is created in interface builder will be shown as landscape only. There will be no need of shouldAutorotateInterfaceOrientation method.